# specify specific types in where clause?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to specify the data types a generic can take as opposed to traits?
Like this:

```
// Purely an example for demonstrative purposes
fn has_a<T>(text: T) -> bool 
where T: String + str {
    text.contains('a')
}
```

If not is there a way to group types into a collection or trait so the possible type of a generic parameter can only take on the listed types? E.g:

```
trait Text { String, str}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics do not have this functionality. If you want to group a couple types together, you can use an `enum` or split your function into separate versions for each type.

```rust
/// This is just an example. Don't use this.
pub enum StringTypes<'a> {
    Owned(String),
    Borrowed(&'a str),
}
```

**However, it is generally better to look for (or create) a trait that provides the functionality you want.** For example, that might look something like this:

```rust
pub trait ContainsA {
    fn contains_a(&self) -> bool;
}

impl ContainsA for String {
    fn contains_a(&self) -> bool {
        self.contains('a')
    }
}

impl ContainsA for str {
    fn contains_a(&self) -> bool {
        self.contains('a')
    }
}
```

Here are some of the most common traits that you may want to consider:

- `AsRef<T>`: Generally if you want to accept an owned type or a reference, you probably want to use the trait bound `AsRef<T>`. When you need to use it you can simply call `x.as_ref()` and you know you will get a `&T` back without consuming the initial value. Some of the most common ways you will see this used are with `AsRef<str>` to accept any string-like type and `AsRef<Path>` to accept file path-like types.
- `ToOwned`: This is a helpful trait which which turns some type into an owned value. You can generally think of this as a smarter version of `Clone` that can handle turning reference types into their owned counterparts (Ex: `str` to `String`).

So in your case, it could be rewritten as follows:

```rust
fn has_a<S: AsRef<str>>(text: S) -> bool {
    text.as_ref().contains('a')
}
```

However, it may be easier to just always accept a `&str` and call it a day.
If your actual use case is related to `contains` and string pattern matching, you may want to look into [`std::str::pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/index.html) on nightly.

Comment: I agree with using `&str` instead of a generic. I'm not sure if it's written down somewhere,  I couldn't find anything, but if you look at arbitrary libraries, you will see that `&str` seems to be best practices; especially because `&String` can be implicitely converted to `&str`. As a very random example, `chrono`'s email header timestamp parser: https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.parse_from_rfc2822